# Possibility to relate to other project file in comments?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to relate/link to other project files within the comments of the source code (C# in this case) in Visual Studio?

I've found you can use `file://` hyperlinks, but those need an absolute path (plus they won't open in the code editor)... there's also `<see cref>`, which works with R#, but that relates to a symbol that must be referenced by the current project, so that doesn't work in my case.

For my specific case, I'd like to somehow relate Entity Framework's entity POCOs to their mapping configuration class (which resides in other project file which is not referenced by the project where the POCOs are defined).

Absolute paths won't work since this project is being worked on several computers with different absolute paths.

There's also [HyperAddin](https://hyperaddin.codeplex.com/) but doesn't seem to have been updated since VS 2008, I'm using 2015.

Any ideas, or add-ins you might have used?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate it with [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/). The simplest command (C#) that requires you to select the relative configuration class file path in the editor (like *Project1\config.xml*) before calling it:

```
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    string relativePath = ts.Text;
    string absolutePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(DTE.Solution.FileName), relativePath);
    DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(absolutePath, null);
```